# spring-boot-devtools doesn't seem to work when i run myJhipsterApp as maven build:spring-boot:run

Tags: jhipster

I have generated a blog app   following a video tutorials of jhipster4 blog demo ,but once i change the .html or .java files in eclipse, the spring-boot did not automatically deploy the changes ,as a result there was nothing changed when i refresh the browser

this is the pom.xml ,

```
  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId> 
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
```

do you know how to fix it  ? thanks.

Comment: For HTML it's normal, it's handled by webpack server and you don't need to refresh browser, it's done by browser-sync asumming you're in angular 2.For java, I don't know it could be due to Eclipse and how you started your java app

Comment: I fix it using this pom:

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin </artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                            <executable>true</executable>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <addResources>true</addResources>
                            <!--
                            Enable the line below to have remote debugging of your application on port 5005
                            <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
                            -->
                        </configuration>
                    <dependencies> 
                       <!--springloaded  hotdeploy --> 
                       <dependency> 
                           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                           <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId> 
                           <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
                       </dependency> 
                    </dependencies> 
                    <executions> 
                       <execution> 
                           <goals> 
                               <goal>repackage</goal> 
                           </goals> 
                           <configuration> 
                               <classifier>exec</classifier> 
                           </configuration> 
                       </execution> 
                    </executions>
</plugin>
```